# SSRS expression change text color

Tags: ssrs-2012

I have text box with expression  (see image).
All text will get 'lightcoaral' color.
I would like to change '|' become black color.
Can you shoe me how to modify the expression.
Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't give a ton of details about the issue at hand, but to do this, you need to create a placeholder and change the markup type to "Interpret HTML tags as style".  It's possible you've already done this, considering the use of HTML tags.  From there the expression should be:

```
= "<font color = 'black' size = '1'>" & " | " 
& "</font><font color = 'lightcoral' size = '1'>" 
& IIF(Trim(First(Fields!ID.Value, "DataSet2")) = "", "None", First(Fields!ID.Value, "DataSet2"))  
& "</font>"
```

It isn't clear if there is meant to be other text before the `" | "` but you simply need an additional `<font>` tag for each segment of text you'd like to color.

So based on the comments, you need another block in front of the `" | "` like this:

```
= "<font color = 'lightcoral' size = '1'>"
& IIF(Trim(First(Fields!ID.Value, "DataSet2")) = "", "None", First(Fields!ID.Value, "DataSet2"))
& "</font><font color = 'black' size = '1'>" & " | " 
& "</font><font color = 'lightcoral' size = '1'>" 
& IIF(Trim(First(Fields!ID.Value, "DataSet2")) = "", "None", First(Fields!ID.Value, "DataSet2"))  
& "</font>"
```

And you'll just need to modify the field from the first statement to what you'll need before the `" | "`.

For reference, the above expressions show as this image in my environment(Left textbox is first expression, right is second):

[image: Left textbox is first expression, right is second]

Another alternative would be to set the entire textbox font color property to lightcoral and simply use the expression:

```
"<font color = 'black' size = '1'>" & " | " & "</font>" 
& IIF(Trim(First(Fields!ID.Value, "DataSet2")) = "", "None", First(Fields!ID.Value, "DataSet2"))
```

Comment: That ' | ' on the keyboard sign or just like ' - ' dash sign . the result should like this<br>AAA(lighcoral color)   | or -  (black color)  BBB(lightcoral color)

Comment: @Tsang  Edited my answer based on your comments.

Comment: Got error 'the value expression for the textrun 'textbox1.paragrapgh[0]. textrun[2] contains error:[bc30201] expression expected.

Comment: @Tsang Did you put this expression into a placeholder object with the "Interpret HTML tags as style" markup type?  Could you show me the exact expression you've entered?  I'm able to copy/paste the exact expression from my answer and put it into a placeholder, or directly into the textbox expression value and it works fine.

Comment: the expression above will get duplicate and no black color " | ".

Comment: if i use this = "<font color = 'lightcoral' size = '1'>"
& IIF(Trim(First(Fields!ID.Value, "DataSet2")) = "", "None", First(Fields!ID.Value, "DataSet2"))
& "</font><font color = 'black' size = '1'>" & " | " 
& "</font><font color = 'lightcoral' size = '1'>" 
& IIF(Trim(First(Fields!ID.Value, "DataSet2")) = "", "None", First(Fields!ID.Value, "DataSet2"))  
& "</font>" then i got  additional  ' | ' black color at then end

Comment: should this work                                                                                           ="<font color = 'lightcoral' size = '1'>" +  <font color = 'black'>" | " & 
iif(First(Fields!ID.Value, "DataSet2") = " " ,"None", 
First(Fields!ID.Value, "DataSet2"))+ "</font>

Comment: What do you mean by duplicate?  I don't know whether you want one `ID` in lightcoral on the left side of a black " | " and another `ID` in light coral on the right?  Or just the black " | " with an `ID` in lightcoral on the right? I just copied your version of my answer into a placeholder and it worked as intended.  Your last comment will not work because you can't nest font tags like that.  You have to close the tag with a `</font>` before you can change the color.

Comment: @Tsang Added an image illustrating my results from the two expressions in my answer.  Which do you need?

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. Please ignore all above an start new one. The expression should like this <br> IIF(Trim(First(Fields!ID.Value, "DataSet2")) = "", "None", First(Fields!ID.Value, "DataSet2")). The result like this AAA - BBB. We can use Font color like able to change the color but I like to have  dash sign " - " become any color.

Comment: @Tsang So you want multiple `IDs` to print?  Because that's more of a issue with your dataset and you should probably start a new question if that's the issue.  You'll need to modify the storedProcedure or query that you're collecting the `IDs` from.  If you still need assistance, I'd suggest starting a new question with the query you're pulling data from and tagging me in a comment when you do and I can come take a look at the issue.  Not sure what you mean by " I like to have dash sign " - " become any color.", but if you start a new question, I'll try to help.